# Accessing subclass method from arraylist of superclass

Tags: java, arraylist

For an assignment, I have an ArrayList of type "Reference". Reference is a parent class to the "Book" class and "Journal" class. If I am allowed to add objects of type "Book" and "Journal" to the Arraylist, why would I be getting an error if I want to access methods of Book and Journal via the following code?

```
          ArrayList.get([someindex]).someBookorJournalMethod()
```

The arraylist itself is of the parent class, and the methods I want to access are only defined for either book or either journal.

EDIT: Here is some code

```
  public class Books extends Reference{

   private String Authors;
   private String Publishers;


      public Books(String CallNum, String Author, String Title, String Publisher, int year,String type)
      {

          super(CallNum,Title,year,type);

          Authors= Author;
          Publishers=Publisher;
      }

public String getAuthor()
{
    return Authors;
}



 public class LibrarySearch {


      private ArrayList<Reference> Library;


      public LibrarySearch()
      {
          Library = new ArrayList<Reference>(100);
      }


      public outputLibrary(){

      for (int i = 0 ; i < Library.size(); i+++)
      {
        if (Library.get(i).getType().equals("Book"))
        {
            System.out.println("Type:book\n" + "Call Number:" +  Library.get(i).getCallNumber() +"\n" + "Authors:" + Library.get(i).getAuthors();)
        }
    }

}
```

IntelliJ is having issues with the line Library.get(i).getAuthors() because it is a method specific to Books. How would I resolve this?

Comment: Instead of `if (Library.get(i).getType().equals("Book"))` you should do `if (Library.get(i) instanceof Book)`. But then it's better not to downcast, but instead implement a toString method as one of the comments below suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you specify the type of a variable, you can only invoke methods that are defined for this type. For example, if you have

```
public class A {
  public void methodA() {
    System.out.println("A");
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public void methodB() {
    System.out.println("B");
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A ab = new B();
    ab.methodB();
  }
}
```

This will not compile, since the type defined for the variable `ab` is `A` and the only visible methods are those that are defined in `A`.

In your case you can simply add a blank method in `Reference`(if you don't want to make the class abstract):

```
public void someBookorJournalMethod() {}
```

Or you can explicitly cast the object you're trying to invoke the method for.

However, it is important to note that both approaches are usually bad practices and should be avoided. If it does not make sense to instantiate `Reference` objects, than make the class `abstract` and define `someBookorJournalMethod` as an abstract method. In your code you're most probably using inheritance in a wrong way.

Comment: I can get away with an empty implementation for a superclass method without compilation problems?

Comment: Yes, if it is `void`.

Comment: but then if the implementation in the subclasses have non void return types, won't that cause an error?

Comment: Yes, this will cause an error, but you can always return something like `null` or `-1`. This won't really matter, since the method will get overridden. This will make the code work, but it's not a proper usage of inheritance.

Comment: @SahilAcharya Reading your `outputLibrary()` method, I see that what you really want to do is implement (by overriding) `toString()` in both your `Book` and `Journal` classes. Then in `outputLibrary()` you don't care which type of Reference you have, just print it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the method of a subclass from the superclass. So you'll need to cast to a Book or a Journal.

```
Reference r =ArrayList.get([someindex]);
if (r instanceof Book) {
    ((Book) r).someBookMethod();
} else if (r instanceof Journal) {
     ((Journal) r).someJournalMethod();
}
```